# Is there a way to prevent the editing of HTML and CSS contents in a page using Firebug-like tools?

Tags: html, javascript, php, css

Is there a way to prevent the editing of HTML and CSS contents in a page using Firebug-like tools?

I found that some users are editing some values in hidden fields and some contents which written between a `div` or `span` tag for gaining some profits. They are doing mostly by editing with help of tools like firebug. Is there any way to identify such modifications? The problem here is that the values they are editing is generated when the page is compiled. The page is developed in PHP. The editing is done mostly in between the `<form>` and `</form>` tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent the editing of HTML and CSS contents in a page using Firebug-like tools?

No. Everything on the user's computer is under the control of the user.

> I found that some users are editing some values in hidden fields and some contents which written between a div or span tag for gaining some profits.

Don't trust the user with that data then. Keep it on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can not stop this. The best way to combat this is to move the processing of these fields to the server. Process this information using a `session` and `php`

Answer (score 0):

You can not prevent anyone from editing the code. No matter what you do, they are ultimately able to rebuild the code from scratch or send the request generated by the form manually.

A possible solution would be to store the values you want not to be changed in a session-variable instead. These can not be modified by the user!

Comment: But if for example we have to store price of multiple contents in an estore, it's not practical.